# python multiple 'for' statement in one row

Tags: python, for-loop

I wanna do some refactoring of my code, in perl I remember was some statement like 
`(a, b, c) = (x, y, z)` it called like 'multiple assigning'. I also heard this thing exists in python, but I need not exactly 'multiple assigning'.

I have 3 lists with same size, and I need to know - can I get items from them by something like this:

```
for a, b, c in a_list, b_list, c_list:
   pass
```

For my tests it just gets first 3 elements of a_list `(a = a_list[0], b = a_list[1], c = a_list[2])` but I need to get one element from a_list `(a = a_list[0])`, one element fro b_list `(b = b_list[0])` and same from `c_list` and to get next items on each iteration.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`zip`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip):

```
for a, b, c in zip(a_list, b_list, c_list):
   pass
```

Your code didn't work because it is actually equivalent to:

```
for lis in (a_list, b_list, c_list):
    a, b, c = lis  #assign the items of list fetched from the `tuple` to a, b ,c
```

Comment: Okay, it works! But what about 'if'-statement? I want to compare many values to one value, how can I do something like this? `if a, b, c, d is None: pass` (To avoid multiple rows in if condition) If this is possible - tell me then about `or` and `and` conditions in the form.

Comment: @VictorPolevoy unclear what you want to happen with that kind of statement, but try using `all(a,b,c,d)` and/or `any(a,b,c,d)`.  Possibly with `not`.

Comment: @VictorPolevoy It's not clear what exactly you want.

Answer (score 5):

You can do:

```
for a, b, c in zip(a_list, b_list, c_list):
   pass
```

If the lists of not of equal length you can use [`itertools.izip_longest`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest) which will use a "fill value" when one list is longer than the other.